# Anthem.NET: Global PostCallBackFunction

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

A project I am working on requires the execution of a client-side script whenever an asynchronous callback is completed. While `$.ajaxStop()` does exactly what I need, I am working with Anthem.NET and their flavor of asynchronous callbacks, and I cannot figure out what the Anthem supported equivalent (if any) is.

```
<anthem:Panel runat="server" ID="Foo" OnClick="Foo_Click" PostCallBackFunction="Bar"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Bar(){
}
</script>
```

Above is an example of an anthem panel with `Bar` as a PostCallBackFunction. I need `Bar` to be executed after *any* callback.

Does anyone know of any alternatives to `$.ajaxStop()` that will execute client-side functions after any Anthem callback is complete?

Answer (score 0):

Anthem is build on MS AJAX, and you can abort a request like this in MS AJAX:

```
var mgr = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
mgr.abortPostBack();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397526%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Does that help you at all?

Comment: I'm not trying to abort a request, I am trying to execute a client-side function after the request - any request - is complete.

Comment: Should that anthem:Panel be an anthem:UpdatePanel?

Comment: If so this post shows how to monitor events with UpdatePanel in MS AJAX: http://runnable.com/UjsSvSNCLJoVAABm/asp-net-how-to-use-update-panel-client-events

Answer (score 0):

I failed to remember that `Page_Load` is triggered at the beginning of each Anthem callback. So,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    Anthem.Manager.AddScriptForClientSideEval("Bar();");
}
```

works just fine.